# How to extract multiple named values from a JSON object with jMeter

Tags: jmeter, json

I want to extract all the serviceItemId's, this object I got it from an external system and I have to verify the contents are correct or not.

The used JSON Object:

```
[
    [
        {
            "serviceItemId": "SGR40400002",
            "deliveryId": "1",
            "unitOfMeasure": "ORDERS"
        },
        {
            "serviceItemId": "SGR40400003",
            "deliveryId": "2",
            "unitOfMeasure": "ORDERS"
        },
        {
            "serviceItemId": "SGR40400002",
            "deliveryId": "3",
            "unitOfMeasure": "ORDERS"
        }
    ]
]
```

How do I extract all the serviceItemId's?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, now you have all `serviceItemId` values extracted into the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   ```
   serviceItemId_1=SGR40400002
   serviceItemId_2=SGR40400003
   serviceItemId_3=SGR40400002
   serviceItemId_matchNr=3
   ```

   [image]
4. You can now verify their values using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

   [image]

Comment: Sorry I am not clear with the question i think so, the above json payload I am getting from the external system, I am getting this payload via queue I have to verify the contents and I am not going to use this as request so pls tell me how to retrieve the values through script